# How do I type the symbol in TeX?

Tags: symbols

How do I type the symbol in attached file?[image: which is highlighted in below file]

Comment: Hi anand. Welcome to `TeX.SX`. An easy way to find an arbitrary symbol is by "drawing" it on `DeTeXify`. This is a web-based application which you can find at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html. Although your example isn't very clear, I think what you're looking for is `\sphericalangle` from package `amssymb` (`\usepackage{amssymb}` to activate). Hopefully this helps you. Good luck!

Comment: @1010011010 Alas, DeTeXify doesn't help in this case. And it is rather not `sphericalangle`. (This is information to those, who would like to close it as the [illusive] duplicate).

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Thanks for pointing it out. The OP wasn't 100% clear on what symbol we were after. Could do with some zooming in (if possible ofc).

Comment: @moose did you try that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, I am not sure if I understand what you mean. Did I try writing the symbol in Detexify? Yes. I got `\sphericalangle` and `\measuredangle`. If that is not the desired result, the question should be reopened. Annad, could you please give a description of the symbol you are looking for (in words) or a higher resolution image of what you are looking for? Is `\sphericalangle` or `\measuredangle` what you searched? If not, what should be different?

Comment: @moose the shown image has a full circle, I don't think detexify has it (or at least my drawing was not good enough to get it to even suggest anything)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Detexify does not have an angle symbol with a full circle. But I am not sure if anand really wants that. I would wait for a comment to clarify the question.

Comment: @moose I have voted for reopening and I encourage others to do the same, I don't see any evidence why you would think that the symbol shown in the image isn't the one wanted, and all three answers given so far provide symbols in that form.

Comment: Probably the best solution is asking one of authors, using such symbols. They are Pascal Hitzler (don't forget `z`) and Anthony Karel Seda.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I searched for 'd-membership relation' and found a couple of documents with the full-circle angle symbol. Ok, I was wrong. I also voted for re-opening. Sorry for closing your question, anand.

Answer (score 9):

May be this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mysym{%
  \mathrel{%
  {%
    \ooalign{\hidewidth$\mkern3mu\circ$\hidewidth\cr$<$}%
  }%
}}

\begin{document}
  \[ x\mysym U\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the unicodes [U+2A79](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a79/index.htm) and [U+2A7A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a7a/index.htm) for this, as they are already defined in `unicode-math`. They are less similar to `\sphericalangle` and thus easier to distinguish. You need Lua- or XeLaTeX for this.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}   

\begin{document} 
\setmathfont{XITS Math} 
    $\ltcir\gtcir$
\setmathfont{Asana Math} 
    $\ltcir\gtcir$
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math} % not available for my machine
   % $\ltcir\gtcir$

{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"2A79}\symbol{"2A7A}}   
{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"2A79}\symbol{"2A7A}}
{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"2A79}\symbol{"2A7A}}
\end{document}
```

For the last three lines, I checked, [which fonts are available](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a79/fontsupport.htm) for this symbol and you might want to look, which [fonts on your machine](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%A9%B9%20-%20LESS-THAN%20WITH%20CIRCLE%20INSIDE%20%28U%2B2A79%29) have it. All three named fonts are nice and very complete. But I am not able to show them right now. Maybe someone else can compile it and add the image.

Here is the screenshot of the `unicode-math` results.

[image]

The first six symbols are relational operators. The last six are not. You may want to introduce macros such as `\newcommand*\myltcir{\mathrel{\text{{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"2A79}}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Inventing new binary relations is hard on the typesetting :)  I can suggest combining it by hand, like the following

```
\newcommand{\lcirc}{<\hspace{-8pt}\circ}
$\lcirc$
```

On the first glance I don't find an existing similar symbol in http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it would be better to do the spacing in `mu` (math units) so that scaling works correctly. Try using this as a limit for a sum, for example.